# AsyncTask not getting excused after app is terminated?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

1. I want perform some check continuously. I have defined AsyncTask as
   follows,

   ```
         new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

                       @Override
                       protected void onPreExecute() {
                           Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
                       }

                       @Override
                       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                           sendData(array);  
                           return null;
                       }

                       @Override
                       protected void onPostExecute(String res) {                    }
                   }.execute(userResponse);
   ```

But when I terminate the application then thread stops execution.

Comment: Obviously, it will exit. If you want to run then use `IntentService` or `Service` for that purpose which will run in the background.

Comment: try to use service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service class demo :-**

```
package com.example.My Application;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

**Activity :-**

```
package com.example.My Application;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   // Method to start the service
   public void startService(View view) {
      startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
   }

   // Method to stop the service
   public void stopService(View view) {
      stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
   }
}
```

**Manifest :-**

Add `<service android:name=".MyService" />`